# I am developing a quiz app. I want to know how to pass the score variable to another page without using the constructor

Tags: flutter

This is my home page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';enter code here
import 'package:quiz_app/main.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  //Color(0xFF7f00ff),#6600cc
  //Color(0xFFe100ff),#cc0066
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          colors: [
                            Color(0xFF7f00ff),
                            Color(0xFFe100ff),
                          ],
                        )
                      ),
                    child: Column(
                    children: [
                     Container(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60,horizontal: 40),
                       child: Image.asset('assets/quiz.gif',),
                     ),
                     Container(                                                     
                          child: Column(                     
                            children: [
                              seriesButton('The Big Bang Theory'),
                              seriesButton('F.R.I.E.N.D.S','/friends'),
                              seriesButton('The 100'),
                              seriesButton('River dale'),
                              seriesButton('Sex Education'),
                              seriesButton('Money Heist'),
                              seriesButton('The Boys'),
                              seriesButton('Stranger things'),
                              seriesButton('Dark'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    
  }

  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  FlatButton seriesButton(String seriesName,[navigator]) {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return FlatButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, navigator);

                      },
                      minWidth: double.infinity, 
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20,horizontal: 0),                    
                      child: Text(seriesName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                      );
  }
}
```

Class I created for questions and options:-

```
class Ques{
late String q,a;
  Ques({this.q='',this.a=''});
  
}

class Options{
 String option1,option2,option3,option4;
 Options({this.option1='',this.option2='',this.option3='',this.option4=''});
}
```

This is a sample page for quiz:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/modal.dart';

class Friends extends StatefulWidget {
  const Friends({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FriendsState createState() => _FriendsState();
}

class _FriendsState extends State<Friends> {
  int n=0;
  int score=0;
  String resultt='';
  List ques=[
    Ques(q:"In which city is Friends set?",a: 'New york city'),
    Ques(q:"What name did Ross accidentally say at the alter?",a: 'Rachel'),
    Ques(q:"What's the name of the coffee shop used by the characters?",a: 'Central Perk'),
    Ques(q:"Who said 'Hey, I'm Chandler, could I BE wearing any more clothes?",a: 'Joey'),
    Ques(q:"What is the name of Phoebe's alter-ego? ",a: 'Regina Phalange'),
    Ques(q:"Who is Chandler and Joey's TV magazine addressed to?",a: 'Miss.Chanandler Bong'),
    Ques(q:"Why did the Friends need to 'Pivot!'?",a: 'They were moving sofa'),
    Ques(q:"What is the name of Rachel's hairless cat?",a: 'Mrs.Whiskerson'),
    Ques(q:"Which of the options describes Ross",a: 'Geeky and lovely'),
    Ques(q:"In the season 6 Thanksgiving episode, what dessert does Rachel try and make?",a: 'Triffle'),
  ];
  List option=[
    Options(option1: 'Los Angeles',option2: 'New york city',option3: 'Manhattan',option4: 'Seattle'),
    Options(option1: 'Rachel',option2: 'Pheobe',option3: 'Charles',option4: 'Emily'),
    Options(option1: 'St. James Perk',option2: 'Nayyar tea shop',option3: 'Central Perk',option4: 'Cafe coffee day'),
    Options(option1: 'Chandler',option2: 'Ross',option3: 'Gunther',option4: 'Joey'),
    Options(option1: 'Pheobe Neeby',option4: 'Regina Phalange',option3: 'Elaine Benes',option2: 'Felula Geller'),
    Options(option1: 'Miss.Chanandler Bong',option2: 'Mrs.Chanel Beng',option3: 'Miss. Chandler Bing ',option4: 'Rachel Greep'),
    Options(option1: 'They were moving sofa',option2: 'They were playing basketball',option3: 'They were playing cards',option4: 'They were doing ballet'),
    Options(option1: 'Mrs.Whiskerson',option2: 'Baldy',option3: 'Kitty',option4: 'Meow'),
    Options(option1: 'Clean and tidy',option2: 'Geeky and lovely',option3: 'Childish and funny',option4: 'Weird and selfless'),
    Options(option1: 'Cheesecake',option2: 'Fajitaas',option3: 'Chocolate cake',option4: 'Triffle'),

  ];
  void clickAnswer(String choice){
    setState(() {
      if(choice==ques[n].a){
        score=score+1;
      }
      if(n<ques.length-1){
      n=n+1;
      }
      else{
         resultt='Your score is $score. Click reset to play again';
      }
    }
    );
  }

  void reset(){
    setState(() {
       n=0;
       score=0;
       resultt='';
    });
   
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body:Container(        
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0,horizontal: 30.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(       
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/friends.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.9),BlendMode.lighten)            
              ),
               ),
      child:Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('Score: $score/10',             
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color:Colors.white,
                 ),
                 ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  reset();
                },
                child: Text('Reset',                              
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration:TextDecoration.underline,
                  color:Colors.white,                 
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                 ),
                 )
                 ),
            ],

          ),
          SizedBox(height:20),
          Container(
            padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:30,horizontal:20),
            height: 130.0,
            width: double.infinity,            
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),          
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            border:Border.all(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
              ),
              child: Text(ques[n].q,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          ),
            SizedBox(height:30),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children:[
                   choicebutton(option[n].option1),
                   SizedBox(height:10),
                   choicebutton(option[n].option2),
                   SizedBox(height:10),
                   choicebutton(option[n].option3),
                   SizedBox(height:10),
                   choicebutton(option[n].option4),
                   SizedBox(height:10),
                    ],
                    )                           
                  ),
        
                
        ],
        
        ) ,
        ) ,
        
    ); 
  
  }
  Widget choicebutton(text) {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20,horizontal:60 ),                                              
                color: Colors.purple[100]!.withOpacity(0.7),
                child: Text(text),
                onPressed:(){
                  clickAnswer(text);                                        
                });
  }
  
}
```

I have multiple sample pages like this so that the user can choose the category.
Here I want to pass the score variable to another page after the last question is over, so that the score is displayed to the with ranking. Since I haven't used score variable in a constructor I don't know how to pass the variable to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a score variable, you can always use shared preferences
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Where should I implement this code?In the data passing page or in the destination page?

Comment: you setInt in passing page and getInt in destination.